# Escaping special characters in cli

Tags: javascript, ruby, command-line-interface, special-characters

I have been asked to escape special characters

I have this env file

```
  APP_AUTH_DOMAIN = blen.pp.com
  APP_DATABASE_URL = https://bebaeio.com
  APP_STORAGE_BUCKET = blepot.com
  APP_ID = 1:2806911447cdcd63f5564ad
  MEASUREMENT_ID = G-0W
```

Here `.` `-` , `:` and `/` should be special characters? The escape for them would be

```
  APP_AUTH_DOMAIN = blen/./pp/./com
  APP_DATABASE_URL = https://bebaeio/./com
  APP_STORAGE_BUCKET = blepot/./com
  APP_ID = 1/:/2806911447cdcd63f5564ad
  MEASUREMENT_ID = G/-/0W
```

Is the above correct? also what would be the escape character for `https://bebaeio.com`

Ps: this the error I got

> We were unable to parse one of your secure environment variables.
>   Please make sure to escape special characters such as ' ' (white
>   space) and $ (dollar symbol) with \ (backslash) . For example,
>   thi$isanexample would be typed as thi\$isanexample. See
>   https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you need to use a \ (backslash) not / (forward slash) for escaping.

```
APP_AUTH_DOMAIN = blen\.pp\.com
APP_DATABASE_URL = https\:\/\/bebaeio.com
APP_STORAGE_BUCKET = blepot\.com
APP_ID = 1\:2806911447cdcd63f5564ad
MEASUREMENT_ID = G\-0W
```

Answer (score 0):

These are bash environment variables. You can either [escape](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html) special characters or [quote](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) the whole value. The latter is usually easier. Also for [assignment](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html), don't put whitespace around `=`.

This should work:

```
APP_AUTH_DOMAIN="blen.pp.com"
APP_DATABASE_URL="https://bebaeio.com"
APP_STORAGE_BUCKET="blepot.com"
APP_ID="1:2806911447cdcd63f5564ad"
MEASUREMENT_ID="G-0W"
```